# Parcellite indicator in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: indicator

I've been happily using **Parcellite** clipboard manager for some time now.
But after upgrading **from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10**, which also meant upgrading Parcellite from 1.1.4 to 1.1.5, I no longer have **Parcellite Unity panel indicator**.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I also tried Parcellite version 1.1.4 which has an "appindicator" debian package at sourceforget.net but it doesn't work either. I agree that the decision against "systray whitelist" was not a good idea at all with so many apps that cannot use the new Ubuntu-specific systray :-(

Comment: Crazy idea in deed, but may well be worth considering if Mark Shuttleworth follows the footsteps of Steve Jobs in terms of exclusivist and monopolist trends ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a fork of Parcellite is available and this fork supports does provide an indicator for Unity:

[Parcellite with Ubuntu AppIndicator? ClipIt!](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/parcellite-has-new-developer-and-new.html)

> Parcellite doesn't have Ubuntu indicator support but for that you can use ClipIt, a Parcellite fork that uses an Ubuntu appindicator and also comes with some other fixes and improvements. The recent changes in Parcellite 0.9.3 have also been included in ClipIt.

The link provide access to a ppa which maybe more recent than `Version: 1.4.1-1.1ubuntu1` which is available in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: I've already done it :-) I remember using ClipIt some time ago but just don't remember why on earth I switched to Parcellite ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Parcellite has had indicator support for a long time, since 1.1.5 (July 2013)
1.2.0 has just been released.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Where can we find out more?

Comment: Thanks, in this case, I'd also like to compare this latest version of Parcellite   with ClipIt. Hoping to find support for one icon for the app, and another one for the indicator, which has been a long-standing bug...